# External HDD ejected improperly, now I can't get it to write/edit

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I've looked up a bunch of different sites and forum posts, but I can't seem to fix my issue. I went to sleep with it plugged in, and when I came back there was an error saying it couldn't mount. I tried all the various terminal commands to fix it, but when I get it to read-only and try running First Aid through Disk Utility, I get the error:

> First Aid process has failed. If possible back up the data on this volume. Click Done to continue.

Does this mean I have to get another HD to move the data over and reformat the drive? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging both it, both power and data, and replugging it back in?

Comment: @agarza yes I have

Comment: What filesystem is on this drive?  Since it seems to be important data to you, don't you already have a backup of it?